# How to add product to cart in Concrete 5

Tags: concrete5

I am using the `core commerce extension`. I created the product and wanted to add the product to the cart programmatically by using the `productID`.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me

```
    $pr = CoreCommerceProduct::getByID(10); //id of product
    $cart = CoreCommerceCurrentOrder::get();

    // add the product to the cart
    $pr = $cart->addProduct($pr, $qty);

    $eventResult = Events::fire('core_commerce_add_to_cart', $cart, $pr, $qty);

    // append attributes to order product
    $attribs = $pr->getProductConfigurableAttributes();
    foreach ($attribs as $at) {
        $at->saveAttributeForm($pr);
    }

    $pr->rescanOrderProductPricePaid();

    // decide wether to increment quantity or add additional line item
    if ($other = $cart->orderContainsOtherProduct($pr)) {
        $cart->removeProduct($pr);
        if (!$other->productIsPhysicalGood()) {
            $newQuant = 1;
        } else {
            $newQuant = $other->getQuantity() + $qty;
        }
        $other->setQuantity($newQuant);
    }
```